# Using Execute Procedure in SQL Server Management Studio - how do I format the value for a user defined table type?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, user-defined-functions

I am trying to test a stored procedure by using the Execute Procedure option in SQL Server Management Studio [Here is a screenshot of the "Execute Procedure" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYxuN.jpg). My stored procedure uses a user defined table type consisting of a bigint.

When I click on the "Execute Procedure", I need to supply the value for my user defined table type. I am not sure how to format the value.... if I put in an integer I get an operand type clash saying my int is not compatible with my user defined table type.

I assume that there is some way to use this "Execute Procedure" call and I am just not familiar with how the value needs to be formatted.

Appreciate any help you can provide.

Thanks!

Comment: We need the code for the user defined table type, procedure and the value you are passing. Will you please post? Also, check out this web link - I suspect it may be how you are defining the parameters in your procedure. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/userdefined-table-type-and-table-valued-parameters-in-stored-procedure-to-reduce-the-code-size-in-code-behind-file

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS, you'll need to declare a variable of the same table type, insert data into the variable, and then execute the proc passing the variable as a parameter.

Instead of using Execute "Stored Procedure...", select "Script Stored Procedure...-->As Execute to-->New Query Editor Window". Then add the needed `INSERT` statements before the `EXECUTE` statement along with assigning values to the other variables.